# Moving Layers In X&Y Direction With Depth By Mouse

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Could you take a look at this site , it's official web site of Coraline animated movie , is there any related article or tutorial to do such navigation technique

[www.coraline.com](http://www.coraline.com/)

If not i will try to explain , layers of movieclips are ordered in z direction when you move your mouse in x & y they move based on depth like semi 3d side walk games, i don't know how really i could explain, it's an old technique and recently i am interested

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect is called parallax. I cannot recommend a specific tutorial, but site has lots of info to get you started.

http://www.productivedreams.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-parallax/

Comment: Thanks you , that's all i need , name of this technique